# Are views assigned to models or models assigned to views in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, chess

I am trying to model a chessboard in Backbone.js. My idea was to create an 8x8 nested array of models that are assigned views. A simplified version of the code is like this:

Inside 'main.js':

```
new App.View.Board({
  model: App.Model.Board()
});
```

And then inside '/model/Board.js':

```
App.Model.Board = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {

    this.squares = new App.Collection.Squares(
      _.flatten(
        _.map(_.range(1, 9), function(y) {
          return _.map(_.range(1, 9), function(x) {
            return new App.Model.Square({
              x: x,
              y: y,
              view: new App.View.Square()
            });
          });
        })
      )
    );

  }
  ...
```

Anyway, I never know whether a model is assigned to a view or a view is assigned to a model. It seems like a slippery slope. Do models get views or do views get models?

Comment: This question belongs better in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ where you can discuss conceptual issues related to programming.  This isn't a pure Q&A type question that StackOverflow wants.

Comment: That's fair. Any idea why the question to which I linked did well, though? Seems even more open ended.

Comment: That other question is much more specific about what it's asking and a single answer could cover most of the various ways to represent the data structure of the chess board with various pros/cons.  That other question probably also belongs in programmers, but is certainly much closer to the borderline and could go either way.  Your question "How to model a chessboard?" is way, way too broad and it would be hard to envision a single best answer that wasn't entirely opinion.  That makes it hard to fit in stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question to be more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views get Models. [When you create a View you can pass it the Model that it will use](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#View-constructor). On the other hand, [a Model does not take a View](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-constructor).

Comment: So right now I have: `Board view -> Board model -> Square model -> Square view`. Should I nest the views instead, like so: `Board view -> Square view -> Square model` and simply have no `Board` model?

Comment: @ggundersen I would avoid putting Views inside Models at all costs. Also I don't really think a chess application is the best use case for Backbone.js.

Comment: @ggundersen if you insist on using Backbone I'd say what you want is `Column/Row Collection -> Square Collection -> Square Model` then you'd have a `Board View` that would take the `Row Collection` and render the 2D array/collection.